# CD /d <x:\folder> failing inside a .cmd script

Tags: windows, command-line, batch-file

I'm stunned with a glitch I've come across while creating some network traffic capture scripts (.cmd) Windows NT6x, Windows 7 and up (tested in Windows 7/8/10).

A plain simple:

```
CD /d x:\net\tools
```

is not working to change to "x:" drive and jump to foler "\net\tools", also no error is reported (not even in ERRORLEVEL)

Any ideas?

Comment: Is X: a mapped drive? How exactly are you launching the script?

Comment: try adding a `net use x: \\computername\net\tools` before the `cd /d x:\net\tools`

Comment: AFAIK, the mapped letters are per-user, which is what @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 may be getting at. In addition, depending on how the drives are mapped they may go idle and cause a failure, but I would expect this to throw an error

Comment: x: is a phisical drive (C:, D:, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

Just debugged the damn thing...

it's incredible but the problem was a "setlocal" directive
is interfering with the CD command...
it interferes even with the X: command...

to test the 'imbroglio' just make a script "x.cmd" like this:

```
setlocal
cd /d c:\windows
```

save the script
put yourself in c:\ or if you have another drive in x:\
execute the script...
and note when the script finish you are not in the c:\windows folder

Weird !!!
'setlocal' should only affect environment variables...